# Hebrew WP 3.5: plugin activated, does not appear in sidebar

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to create a custom post type with mandatory custom fields. I've followed the [Adding Custom Fields to a Custom Post Type, the Right Way](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/adding-custom-fields-to-a-custom-post-type-the-right-way) tutorial,  and installed the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin on my Hebrew Wordpress 3.5:

[image]

The new custom post type ("Books") appears on the side bar, as expected. But there is no `Advanced Custom Fields` item on the sidebar, although the plugin is installed and activated.

I've tried installing using the web interface and opening the zip file directly, with no results.

How do I get the `Advanced Custom Fields` to appear on my sidebar menu?

Answer (score 0):

"[Advanced custom field plugin not showing in admin sidebar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85416/advanced-custom-field-plugin-not-showing-in-admin-sidebar)" gave me a useful clue.

Finally, I've moved int the plugin directory, and cloned the git repo directly:

```
git clone git://github.com/elliotcondon/acf4.git advanced-custom-fields
```